# sorting data in firebase Firestore swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore database which stores data i am doing a query to pull documents into a tableview i need the data to be sorted a specific way so i added to my document a string called order and am trying to sort the data through that. For 1-10 documents it works fine but after that it stops ordering correctly. It still retrieves everything but in the wrong order.

```
   db.collection(child).order(by: "order").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
        } else {
            for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
```

am i doing anything wrong i am following the firbase docs

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the actual ordered items and where exactly the sorting went wrong after 1-10 documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you Doug for the comment i went back into my firestore database to see what is changing after 10 items i think it might have been due to the order field being a string i changed it to int and it started working